# Python packing a struct won't accept the string argument

Tags: python

I have a bit of code that should make a raw binary packet:

```
 def sendPacket(self, sendSocket, recvName, recvPort, lostVal, message):
    packorder = 'iH?' + str(len(message.data)) + 's'
    print(packorder)
    raw_msg = pack(packorder, message.num, int(message.chk_sum), bool(message.isLast), message.data)
    generate = random.randint(0, 10000) #random value to check if packet should be sent
    if(lostVal > generate): 
        sendSocket.sendto(raw_msg, (recvName, recvPort)) #sending packet size to server
```

When I try to run it I get this error:

```
raw_msg = pack(packorder, message.num, int(message.chk_sum),bool(message.isLast), message.data)
error: argument for 's' must be a string
```

packorder prints out as:

```
iH?1024s
```

I initially had everything in packorder in the file as it was but I thought it would change if I made it's own variable.

packorder is a string, do I need a different way to show the value 1024?

Comment: What's the type of `message.data`?

Comment: it is a list of strings.

Comment: check the definition of `pack` method using `help(pack)`. You'll see what's the s argument and to what it corresponds in your case.